# How to implement a security by signing web requests against changes (postman etc.)

Tags: oop, security, encryption, request

We have a web service layer as dynamic infrastructure. You can send entity name and filter conditions according to UI requirements.

We want to prevent users accessing other data within their authorization by changing different parameters from web request via postman tools etc.

I'm looking for the most accurate pattern to do this, can friends who have experience in this domain to share information? I plan to set some rule based solutions to backendside or sign request with originial filter data.

Comment: I might be missing something. If there is a parameter that you don't want the user to change, why is that a parameter? If there is no server-side session, it might make sense to sign state and store in the client, some frameworks do that, but it's a little tricky. In short, this needs more info.